# How to show new opened tab using jquery/bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm building a backend for a support system using jquery. I now have a real time chat working (using polling), and I now want to be able to open several chats in tabs that can be opened and closed. So I copied and edited a jquery/bootstrap example from [this page](http://jeykeu.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/dynamically-add-remove-and-re-number-tabs-in-twitter-bootstrap/). Next to it, I'll have a list of users, and when someone clicks a user it should open a new tab with a chat with that respective user. The tabs work pretty well, but I now want to pass a user_id to the tab so that I can open a chat in that tab. Since I'm not so proficient with Javascript I'm kinda unsure how to do this. The code I have so far is pasted below.

Does anybody know how I can pass an argument from a link to the tab? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
I found the answer! I just need to use a class and an id in the button like this: `<a href="javascript:;" class="btnAddPage" id="someid1" role="button">Add Page with id 1</a>`, and after that I can get the id in the addTab function using `this.id`.

Thanks anyway!

```
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageNum = 1;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Add a Tab
            $('#btnAddPage').click(function () {
                pageNum++;
                $('#pageTab').append(
                    $('<li><a href="#page' + pageNum + '">' +
                        'Page ' + pageNum +
                        '<button class="close" type="button" ' +
                        'title="Remove this page">×</button>' +
                        '</a></li>'));

                $('#pageTabContent').append(
                    $('<div class="tab-pane" id="page' + pageNum +'">Dit is de content</div>'));

                $('#page' + pageNum).tab('show');

            });

            // Remove a Tab
            $('#pageTab').on('click', ' li a .close', function () {
                var tabId = $(this).parents('li').children('a').attr('href');
                $(this).parents('li').remove('li');
                $(tabId).remove();
                // reNumberPages();
                $('#pageTab a:first').tab('show');
            });

            // Click Tab to show its content
            $("#pageTab").on("click", "a", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .nav-tabs > li .close {
            margin: -3px 0 0 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 5px 0;
            float: right;
        }
        .nav-tabs > li a[data-toggle=tab] {
            float: left!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="btnAddPage" role="button">Add Page</a>
    <ul id="pageTab" class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>
    <div id="pageTabContent" class="tab-content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't understand your problem... You can't put the user_id in an attribute of a tab-pane ?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud - Ah, that's indeed a nice idea. The thing is now that I need to know which user_id I need to put into the tab-pane. I already use the id of the button I press to activate the function to add the tab. How do I know which button/link was pressed? I.e. how do I give an argument from the link to the javascript function?

Comment: I don't see a user_id on your script

Comment: @ClémentAndraud - I know, thats the thing. I don't know where to put it in the link (as an id, class or something else?) so that I can pass it to the function that adds a tab.

Comment: Nevermind! I now see I can use a class and an id for the button, the class to refer it to the function, the id to use in the tab. Thanks anyway!